# CoreOS Unit Failed on Launched

Tags: docker, virtualization, coreos

I tried launching a service using `chat.service` unit file on a CoreOS and it failed:

```
// chat.service
[Unit]
Description=ChatApp

[Service]
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill simplechat1
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm simplechat1
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker pull jochasinga/socketio-chat
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -p 3000:3000 --name simplechat1 jochasinga/socketio-chat
```

`fleetctl list-units` shows:

```
UNIT            MACHINE                     ACTIVE  SUB
chat.service    cfe13a03.../<virtual-ip>    failed  failed
```

However, if I changed the `chat.service` to just:

```
// chat.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run -p 3000:3000 <mydockerhubuser>/socketio-chat
```

It ran just fine. `fleetctl list-units` shows:

```
UNIT            MACHINE                     ACTIVE  SUB
chat.service    8df7b42d.../<virtual-ip>    active  running
```

**EDIT**
Using `journalctl -u chat.service` I got:

```
Jun 02 00:02:47 core-01 systemd[1]: Started chat.service.
Jun 02 00:02:47 core-01 systemd[1]: chat.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=125/n/a
Jun 02 00:02:47 core-01 docker[8924]: docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint clever_tesla on network brid
Jun 02 00:02:47 core-01 systemd[1]: chat.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 02 00:02:47 core-01 systemd[1]: chat.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 02 00:02:58 core-01 systemd[1]: Stopped chat.service.
Jun 02 00:03:08 core-01 systemd[1]: Stopped chat.service.
```

What had I done wrong in the first `chat.service` unit file? Any guidance is appreciated.

Running [Vagrant version of CoreOS (stable)](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant.git) on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ExecStartPre= command doesn't seem to have a docker subcommand in it. Did you mean to use `pull`?

Reading the journal for the unit should get you more information: `journactl -u chat.service`

Comment: Dang that was a stupid mistake. Let me fix that and see if it works and I'll come back. Thanks for the journal tip.

Comment: It seems like the problem wasn't with the missing `pull`. I've updated the unit file and added the `journalctl` log. With the first version of `chat.service` it seems to fail with 'signal'.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the journal using @Rob suggestion and some research, it appears that docker couldn't create an endpoint at the port 3000 because on the OS there was a running docker process on that port.

Simply stop the process with `docker stop <processname>` and re-launching with `fleetctl start chat` solved the problem.